# How can I write a comparator with a intermediate variable for stl sort

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

```
class Point    
{    
    int x;  
}    
static Point referencePoint;
struct Comparator
{
    bool AbsComparator(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {    
        return abs(p1.x - referencePoint.x) < abs(p2.x - referencePoint.x);
    }   
};    
list<Point> points;
points.sort(Comparator::AbsComparator);
```

But I CANNOT use a static referencePoint for multithreading safe, is there any other way??
Thanks.

Comment: if your referencePoint is used as read-only sure you can

Comment: You may be able to use [thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (TLS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it part of `Comparator`:

```
struct Comparator
{
    Point referencePoint;

    Comparator(Point referencePoint): referencePoint(referencePoint) {}

    Comparator(const Comparator& rhs) {
        referencePoint = rhs.referencePoint;
    }

    bool operator()(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) const
    {    
        return abs(p1.x - referencePoint.x) < abs(p2.x - referencePoint.x);
    }   
};    

...

points.sort(Comparator(refP));
```

Comment: Better make the `operator()` a const function!

Comment: Also, the copy-constructor is not needed. The compiler generated one is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply save the `referencePoint` or rather the integer value inside `Point` as a member inside your `Comparator`, that way you always access it in the comparator function.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid global variables. That is start of writing multi-threaded code.

Use local variables instead:

```
Point referencePoint(10,20); //use local variable!

points.sort(Comparator(referencePoint));
```

Or simpy this,

```
points.sort(Comparator(Point(10,20)));
```

where `Comparator` is a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) defined as:

```
struct Comparator
{
    Point referencePoint;

    explicit Comparator(const Point & pt) : referencePoint(pt) {}

    bool operator() (const Point& p1, const Point& p2) const
    {    
        return abs(p1.x - referencePoint.x) < abs(p2.x - referencePoint.x);
    }   
};
```

You're done!

Notice the implementation of `operator()`. This makes the class a functor.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I dont see any advantage of `explicit` in this case, do you?

Comment: I don't see any advantage to being implicit. It's not of those rare case where one writes a new Number class. By default, I tend to write all "mono-argument" constructors as `explicit`. At least I'll be notified if ever it is used implicitly, while the reverse is not true :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Convincing argument. Thanks. :-) (edited the post)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store this variable, either in a destructured or structured manner.

```
// destructured (only store what you need)
class ReferenceComparator {
public:
  explicit ReferenceComparator(int x): _x(x) {}
  explicit ReferenceComparator(Point const& p): _x(p.x) {}

  bool operator()(Point const& left, Point const& right) const {
    return abs(left.x - _x) < abs(right.x - _x);
  }

private:
  int _x;
}; // class ReferenceComparator
```

And then use it as:

```
list.sort(ReferenceComparator(myReferencePoint));
```

I would advise not using a `list` if you need sorting through. `list` are not good at it...